# Converting SQL query to LINQ to Entities Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to convert it into entity framework Lambda Expression, but i'm not getting proper syntax...

What will be the Entity Framework Lambda Expression of this SQL query:

```
Select max(Number) from table1 WHERE Date > '2014-01-04'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
entities.table1.Where(x=>x.Date>(new DateTime(2014,1,4))).Max(x=>x.Number)
```